# Iterate through table data and fill array with row and td values

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to iterate through a tables rows and have each row be an array, and within that, have all the text of the individual cells as an array within the first array.  So here's my desired output:

```
[
    [row1][
              [td element1 from row 1],
              [td element2 from row 1]  
    ],
    [row2][
              [td element1 from row 2],
              [td element2 from row 2]

    ]
]
```

Here's my code:

```
           page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
            table = page.at('table#ctl00_MainContent_gvSearchResults')
            rows = Array.new
            rowCells = Array.new
            cells = Array.new

            table.search('tr').each do |tr|
                tr.search('td').each do |cell|
                    cells.push(cell.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip)

                end
                rowCells.push(cells)
            end

            p rowCells
```

This is returning the following results where the values are the td elements from ALL the rows.  Its almost right, as it returns an array for each row, but within that array for each row, it puts all the cells for all the rows, so each row array has the same values.

```
[
    [0] [
            [0] "value1",
            [1] "value2" 
        ]
]
```

Comment: You need to reinitialize `cells` after every iteration of a row.

Comment: can you tell me how I would do that specifically?  This is like my second day on ruby, so I'm basically an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinitialize `cells` when you start a new row:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
table = page.at('table#ctl00_MainContent_gvSearchResults')
rowCells = Array.new

table.search('tr').each do |tr|
  cells = Array.new
  tr.search('td').each do |cell|
    cells.push(cell.text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "").strip)
  end
  rowCells.push(cells)
end

p rowCells
```